# Linq datetime date match in query c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to match Datetime.Now's only year(as instance Today is 2014).However i could not do inside of linq query by using datetime.now's year.

```
LevyServiceHelper.GetAllLevyFee().
List.Where(s=>s.ValidDate==Datetime Today Year).ToList();
```

How can i match Datetime Today Year with s.ValidDate ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of `ValidDate`?

Comment: it is a datetime (10-10-2014)

Comment: @JohnElizabeth: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711196/closure-over-variable-gives-slightly-worse-performance-how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LevyServiceHelper.GetAllLevyFee().
List.Where(s=>s.ValidDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year).ToList();
```

Comment: @JohnElizabeth: Will fail when while executing query, year changes.

Comment: How come ? may you please tell ?

Comment: do you mean if execute exactly on new year's eve?

Comment: Valid point, but then your query will have last years data. Mine will have some of each year. Not sure which one is more correct.

Comment: Whose answer is best ?

Comment: @JohnElizabeth: Its upto you :). I have taken year in the beginning and searched collection on that variable making sure results are filtered on a single integer and not `DateTime.Now.Year`.

Comment: If you give + point it will be 15 point :) i can give plus point for both of you thanks for all to all

Comment: @Nikhil your solution introduces a closure over the `yr` variable so it has slightly worse performance

Comment: @NedStoyanov: No its not. Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711196/closure-over-variable-gives-slightly-worse-performance-how

Comment: You are right, despite the closure your method is faster so I would say it is the better solution.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
LevyServiceHelper.GetAllLevyFee()

int yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
List.Where(s => s.ValidDate.Year == yr).ToList();
```

I hope `s.ValidDate` is `DateTime`.

Ned's answer will work for 99.99% of the times. But will fail when while executing query, year changes where as I have taken year in the beginning meaning all validation will happen on same criteria.

Comment: I'd definitely go with this answer. Not only is its performance *much better* than the other one. This operation behaves atomically in respect to the date, as pointed out already. When executing this on new year's eve, you do not want some results of the current year and some of the next (or last, depending how you see it) year. You'd generally expect the function to behave atomically in this respect, i.e. that is is executed at a precise *point* in time, not over a timespan.