# "Closure over variable gives slightly worse performance". How?

Tags: c#

While giving answer to an SO question, I was told that my solution will introduce a closure over variable so it will have slightly worse performance. So my question is:

1. How will there be a closure?
2. How will it affect performance?

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696991/linq-datetime-date-match-in-query-c-sharp/24697022#24697022)

```
List.Where(s => s.ValidDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Year).ToList();
```

Here is my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697022/1011959). I introduced the variable `yr` to store year.

```
int yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
List.Where(s => s.ValidDate.Year == yr).ToList();
```

Here it is in the answer's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697017/1011959)

Comment: These two code snippets have different semantics. If it is run over new year's eve and the year changes between operations you get different results. And in the end – I assume – using the closure code will be faster, since you don't have to create new `DateTime` instances with every loop iteration and you don't have to access two additional properties (which introduce another level of indirection).

Comment: @knittl in the original question this was mentioned in the comments. But where is the closure introduced?

Comment: Well, honestly shouldn't the solution with the closure be faster ? (it works differently -> like the 2 are not equivalent). But if anything it should be faster?

Comment: @knittl: I mentioned that problem. That's why created variable. But where is closure and performance hit.?

Comment: The closure is introduced, because the lambda accesses a variable from the outer scope, it closes over the value of `yr`. The C# compile will generate a new class with a field which holds the `yr`. All references to `yr` will be replaced with the new field and the original `yr` will not even exist in the compiled code.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Are you asking WHERE is the closure ? You're closing on the variable `yr` (creating a closure). As far as the performance. I'd like to know why it would be slower (I don't think so).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, those two solutions are not functionally equivalent (If you fix comparing a date with an int (`.Date == .Today.Year`)):

- The first snippet re-evaluates `DateTime.Today.Year` for each value of the list, which can give different results when the current year changes during iteration
- The second snippet stores the current year and re-uses that, so all items in the resulting list will have the same year. (I'd personally take this approach, as I want to make sure the result is *sane*).

The closure is introduced because the lambda accesses a variable from its outer scope, it closes over the value of `yr`. The C# compile will generate a new class with a field which holds the `yr`. All references to `yr` will be replaced with the new field and the original `yr` will not even exist in the compiled code

I doubt there will be a performance penalty by introducing a closure. If any, the code using the closure will be faster, since it does not have to create new `DateTime` instances for every list item and then dereference two properties. It only has to access the field of the compiler-generated closure class which holds the int value of the current year. (Anybody who wants to compare the generated IL code or profile the two snippets? :))

Answer (score 6):

In addition to knittl's answer I wanted to attempt and measure the performance with and without a closure, here is what my test looks like:

```
internal class SomeData {
    public DateTime ValidDate { get; set; }
    // other data ...
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Test with closure
        IEnumerable<SomeData> data1 = CreateTestData(100000);
        stopWatch.Start();
        int yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
        List<SomeData> results1 = data1.Where(x => x.ValidDate.Year == yr).ToList();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("With a closure - {0} ms", stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
        // ### Output on my machine (consistently): With a closure - 16 ms

        stopWatch.Reset();

        // Test without a closure            
        IEnumerable<SomeData> data2 = CreateTestData(100000);
        stopWatch.Start();
        List<SomeData> results2 = data2.Where(x => x.ValidDate.Year == DateTime.Today.Year).ToList();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Without a closure - {0} ms", stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
        // ### Output on my machine: Without a closure - 33 ms
    }

    private static IEnumerable<SomeData> CreateTestData(int numberOfItems) {
        var dt = DateTime.Today;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            yield return new SomeData {ValidDate = dt};
        }
    }
}
```

Bottom line from my tests - as I expected the version with the closure is considerably faster.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a naive time measurement, merely to complement knittl's answer.

The result is that the version that evaluates `DateTime.Now` every time is more than 10 times *slower* than your code.

Results on my machine: T1: 8878 ms; T2: 589 ms. (Maximum optimization, no debugger, etc).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var things = new List<Something>();
        var random = new Random(111);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            things.Add(new Something(random.Next(2010, 2016)));
        }

        // to avoid measuring the JIT compilation and optimization time
        T1(things);
        T2(things);

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            T1(things);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            T2(things);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void T1(List<Something> list)
    {
        var result = list.Where(x => x.ValidDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).ToList();
    }

    private static void T2(List<Something> list)
    {
        var yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
        var result = list.Where(x => x.ValidDate.Year == yr).ToList();
    }
}

class Something
{
    public Something(int year)
    {
        this.ValidDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    }

    public DateTime ValidDate { get; private set; }
}
```